# datagridview index out of bounds error in event when no index is being set

Tags: c#, events, datagridview, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a datagridview with 3 frozen columns at the left and then the 4th column I want always displayed on the right. The remaining columns are displayed between columns 3 and 4, and are numbered in their headers (with 1, 2, 3, 4, ...). I allow the users to reorder these columns, but I want the column headers to remain in numeric order. The idea is that the user should see it as reordering the data in the columns, not the columns themselves. Column 4 is labeled "New", and if the user attempts to put data into it, a new column is created and the data is added to it instead, which is part of why I want it always on the right.

To accomplish this, I use the following ColumnDisplayIndexChanged event:

```
private void dgvTreeLevels_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e) {
    switch(e.Column.Index) {
       case 0:
       case 1:
       case 2: //prevents columns 0, 1, 2 from being reordered, (freezing just prevents them from being switched with 3+)
          SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(delegate(object o) {
             if (e.Column.DisplayIndex != e.Column.Index) e.Column.DisplayIndex = e.Column.Index;
          }, null);
          break;
       case 3: //Displays always on the right
          SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(delegate(object o) {
             if (e.Column.DisplayIndex != dgvTreeLevels.Columns.Count - 1)
                e.Column.DisplayIndex = dgvTreeLevels.Columns.Count - 1;
          }, null);
          break;
       default: //Numbered columns
          e.Column.HeaderText = (e.Column.DisplayIndex - 2).ToString();
          break;
    }
 }
```

Most of the time it works fine. But occasionally the line

```
              e.Column.HeaderText = (e.Column.DisplayIndex - 2).ToString();
```

is thowing an ArgumentOutOfRangeException stating that the Index is out of range. Since it doesn't set any indexes, this is particularly perplexing. I am not able to reliably create the error. It just pops up on occasions as I am testing the functionality. I think it may be related to attempting to move a numbered column past the right-most, but the error pops up later as I am doing other things.

Checking in the debugger shows that all of the elements in the line are defined and have the correct values. I have no clue why there is an error. The stack trace is

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  Message="Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index"
  Source="mscorlib"
  ParamName="index"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.GetColumnDisplayRectanglePrivate(Int32 columnIndex, Boolean cutOverflow)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean cutOverflow)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.GetCellAdjustedDisplayRectangle(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean cutOverflow)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.InvalidateCellPrivate(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnColumnHeaderGlobalAutoSize(Int32 columnIndex)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellValueChanged(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell.SetValue(Int32 rowIndex, Object value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn.set_HeaderText(String value)
       at Customizable_Reports.frmReport.dgvTreeLevels_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged(Object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.FlushDisplayIndexChanged(Boolean raiseEvent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.CorrectColumnDisplayIndexesAfterDeletion(DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnRemovedColumn_PreNotification(DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnCollection.RemoveAtInternal(Int32 index, Boolean force)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnCollection.RemoveAt(Int32 index)
       at Customizable_Reports.frmReport.RemoveEmptyColumns()
       at Customizable_Reports.frmReport.dgvTreeLevels_CellClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at Customizable_Reports.Program.Main()
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 0):

Further testing showed that the error arose when a higher-numbered column was moved in front of a lower-numbered column, then later was deleted. The error would then occur when the header text of the lower-numbered column was updated in the ColumnDisplayIndexChanged event as a result of the deletion.

You can test this by creating a new Winform application, placing a datagridview on the form with two columns and allowing the user to reorder them. Add a button and the following two events:

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     dataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(1);
  }

  private void dataGridView1_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e) {
     e.Column.HeaderText = e.Column.DisplayIndex.ToString();
  }
```

Run the application, drag column 2 in front of column 1, then press the button. Note that it is necessary to give the columns unique headers for this error to occur. Setting `e.Column.HeaderText = "test";` instead does not produce the error.

To me, this seems like a bug in WinForms, rather than in this programming. But I don't know enough about what is going on to be sure.

Passing the command to the current synchronization context appears to fix the problem:

```
SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(delegate(object o) {
     e.Column.HeaderText = e.Column.DisplayIndex.ToString();
}, null);
```